# Record Camera from iPhone and use as overlay in another video

Tags: iphone, video, record

I know how to record a video from the camera on the iPhone, my question, is it possible to take the recording and overlay it on a saved video and save it out as another file?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so. Not using an standard framework. You could probably do something involving screen capture and combing a load of images to make a video. But it would be complicated.